# DIV height to GROW UP based on inner elements

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="left" style="position: relative; min-height: 300px;">
    <div id="fullBarrels" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0;">
      <div class="fullBarrel">
        <img class="barrel" src="Not Used.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="fullBarrel">
        <img class="barrel" src="Not Used.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="fullBarrel">
        <img class="barrel" src="Not Used.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="fullBarrel">
        <img class="barrel" src="Not Used.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="fullBarrel">
        <img class="barrel" src="Not Used.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="fullBarrel">
        <img class="barrel" src="Not Used.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="fullBarrel">
        <img class="barrel" src="Not Used.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="fullBarrel">
        <img class="barrel" src="Not Used.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="center">
    <img src="70.png" />
  </div>

  <div id="right">
    <div class="emptyBarrels">
      <div class="emptyBarrel">
        <img class="barrel" src="Used.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  background: orange;
  margin: 8em auto 1em auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#center {
  background: red;
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 30%;
}

#center img {
  height: 300px;
}

#left {
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
}

#right {
  background: brown;
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
}

#message {
  background: gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.fullBarrel {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0.5em 0.5em 0 0;
}

.emptyBarrel {
  float: right;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em;
}

img.barrel {
  height: 100px;
}
```

How do I make the yellow div (id="left") **grow up** with the content inside of it? The items are being added from the bottom up - correctly, but the yellow div is not growing beyond the min-height, which is making the inner elements be cut off.

[image]

See how the blue `divs` are going beyond yellow? They are aligning to the bottom of the yellow `div`, though. I would like to have the blue ones bottom align to the yellow, and for yellow to grow up in order to make room for additional blue ones (and also for the orange wrapper). It seems the height of the yellow `div` is fixed to `min-height` even though it does not have the actual height.

Comment: Could you add some placeholder images to your snippet so we can see what the content is doing? Thanks

Comment: For starters take that `position:absolute` out of the fullbarrels tag.

Comment: Note: The `<img>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Comment: @Rob Rhere is no `class=left`, however there is `id=left`, which is what is also referenced in the CSS.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for pointing it out. Any chance of knowing how to move forward now that the question is clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using flex solves this and causes no headache whatsoever. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Try not defining the height of *#wrapper*. That should do it. I think.

EDIT: Another approach (which is not that clean to be honest) would be to wrap everything in a table cell. Those adjust to their contents in height and width. If `width="100%"`, however, there should be no problem.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure if `#wrapper` has height.